# Is there a web scraping library that can get paginated information?

Tags: html, web-scraping

I wanted to know is there a web page scraping library (haven't chosen the language yet, it will depend on the library) that interacts with the page ?

What I mean is, for example we have information, paginated in multiple pages, is it possible to find a library that interacts with the web page and get all the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)?

You can use it directly from the command line or with (almost) any modern programming language.

Comment: I don't know why this answer received a downvote. I upvoted you since this is a good answer. While cURL by itself is not a "scraping" library, it does pave the way for processing HTML.

Comment: I don't know why my question received a downvote and they want to close it ? I have really searched for this before asking and haven't found anything ... thank you for your answer btw, it seems like what I am searching for

Comment: @Khalil - the question might have been upvoted as it is rather broad. Stack Overflow questions generally need to contain code, or at least demonstrate solid prior research.

Answer (score 3):

Any language can do this, and there are suitable frameworks for many of them. Consider frameworks that will let you select a link using XPath or CSS, and then run a "click" method upon it. Note that frameworks that do this generally don't do any clicking at all - they just follow the link in a highly simplified browser environment. This feature will be very useful when clicking pagination links.

- For PHP, consider Goutte - I'm using this for scraping and, since it is powered by Guzzle, it is extremely powerful.
- For Python, consider Scrapy. I've not used it myself, but it is mentioned a lot on this site.
- If you don't need any programmatic interface, however, look at Import.io - they have a free application that may be of interest.

That said, some web pages use JavaScript for the pagination. In general, this is rather unnecessary, but if you want to scrape such sites, you'll either need to use a simple scraper on the underlying AJAX call, or you'll need to use a headless browser, so that you can execute JavaScript. This is much slower, since it is more complicated.